# Can't get getActiveSheet() from undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy a row from sheet "Name1" to sheet "Name2" when entering "ok" in cell 1 (column 1) but I couldn't fix this error in the title (Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" from undefined). I have tried all those commented lines but no luck, I'm editing the cell and enter "ok" in that cell but not working.

```
   function onEdit2(e) {
      //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ss = e.source;
     //var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1yAJY3gO46A7Wr_fYtVHAB_wSElUdG2kkiH1clRg9o8k").getSheetByName('Name1');
   var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var r = e.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Name1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "ok") {
     var row = r.getRow();
     var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
     var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Name2");
     var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
     s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
     s.deleteRow(row);
 }
}
```

the error I'm getting is

```
  TypeError: Can not call method "getActiveSheet" from undefined. (Row 135).
```

I edited those first lines to those

```
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      // var ss = e.source;
      //var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1yAJY3gO46A7Wr_fYtVHAB_wSElUdG2kkiH1clRg8o9k").getSheetByName('Lista');
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var r = e.source.getActiveRange();  // I get error now here can't call getactiverange from undefined .
```

Comment: you should use the Logger() and print out the errors you get.

Comment: edited my error @SujayPhadke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At this line:**

```
var targetSheet = s.getSheetByName("Name2");
```

You're running the [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) on the **Sheet** and it needs to run on the **Spreadsheet** to be able to get the other **Sheet** `Name2` , so just change that line to:

```
var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Name2");
```

Also rename your function from `onEdit2()` to the reserved function name `onEdit()` so it gets triggered, or create an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

Your function should look like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   var ss = e.source;
   var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var r = e.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Name1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "ok") {
     var row = r.getRow();
     var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
     var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Name2"); // Changed
     var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
     s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
     s.deleteRow(row);
 }
}
```

I created an example Spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yZMJnMcI8S9Yp40wpF4mNT9phXsXHVh6e0nZCFOzPnM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Have changed both your suggestions but nothing works .

Comment: i have looked your example but how it works ? what i edit to work ?

Comment: The same, just type `ok` on the first column, you can see the function on **Tools > ScriptEditor**

Comment: hahaha it works now :) . So i didnt have to enter the function , its built in now :) . I mean onEdit() is working automatically without puting it somewhere . But how if its custom function and i foreaxmple need to call it ??

Comment: Yes because it's a Simple Trigger, take a look at the [offical documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit). About the custom function question, `A custom function cannot affect cells other than those it returns a value to. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells.` ([Source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values))

Answer (score 0):

When a sheet is edited, the function **onEdit()** is called, not **onEdit2()**. **onEdit2** seems to be your custom function, so you must be calling that yourself from somewhere else. (maybe from within onEdit()?). If so, are you passing the event object *e* while calling it? (You have to call it like this:

```
onEdit2(e);
```

If you're not passing the parameter *e*, then you will get the error you're seeing, since *ss* will be undefined.

ref: [GAS-trigger-events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: i have also passed function onEdit(e); with same code but didnt work also

Comment: sorry i don't see it in your code. Where are you calling onEdit2(e) above?

Comment: im calling `onEdit2(e) ` in sheet  `Name1`